# Computerbegriffe mit Artikel?

Tags: article, technical-terminology

Die vollständige Frage lautet:
Werden die Informatik-Abstraktionen, die einen Namen haben können, wie z.B.: Dateien, Verzeichnisse, Objekte, Anwendung, usw... mit einem Artikel geschrieben?

- in der file.docx Datei ...
- in file.docx Datei ...

Unterfrage: Soll der Name nach oder vor dem Substantive stehen?

- in der file.docx Datei ...
- in der Datei file.docx ...

Weitere Beispiele:

- ... mit (dem?) TEST.01 Label ...
- ... mit (dem?) TODO Tag ...
- ... in (dem?) Release Repository ...
- ... mit (dem?) "ipconfig" Befehl ...

Comment: In der Datei file.docx...

Comment: Wie @Stephie sagte: die traditionelle deutsche Sprechweise lautet "Artikel" "Typbezeichnung" "Individualname". Derzeit geht der Trend aber stark zur englischen Variante "Artikel" "Individualname" "Typbezeichnung", besonders in der Informatik. Beispielsweise wäre früher der Titel "The C++ programming language" übersetzt worden als "Die Programiersprache C++". Heute schreibt selbst der Verlag offiziell "Die C++ Programmiersprache". Es bleibt abzusehen, ob die traditionelle Konstruktion ganz verschwinden wird.

Comment: Die erste Variante bringt mich dazu, einen vermeintlichen Grammatikfehler ausbessern zu wollen: *I**m** File file.odt …*

Comment: Die letzten 2 Sätze haben kein Verb. Was ist mit (dem) Todo-Tag oder dem TEST.01-Label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zur ersten Frage: *Werden die Informatik-Abstraktionen, die einen Namen haben können, [...] mit einem Artikel geschrieben?*

Die Begriffe selbst werden mit Artikel geschrieben. Nicht notwendig ist der Artikel, wenn man nur den Namen verwendet. Dies wird deutlich, wenn man zum Beispiel über Tiere redet:

```
die Datei               der Tiger
die Datei „file.txt”    der Tiger „Shere Khan”
file.txt                Shere Khan
```

Umgangssprachlich kommt es jedoch oft vor, dass ein Artikel vor einen Namen gestellt wird, siehe [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Namen.html).

---

Zur Frage: *Soll der Name nach oder vor dem Substantiv stehen?*

Nach dem Substantiv, wenn es denn tatsächlich ein Name ist. Vor dem Substantiv (als ein Wort oder mit Bindestrich), wenn es eine Erläuterung ist. Bei einigen der genannten Beispiele ist es nicht sofort ersichtlich, ob es sich um Namen oder vielmehr Beschreibungen handelt:

```
Das Release-Repository „Release 2.0”...
```

Ein anderes Beispiel:

- „Das *Konzert „Geigen”* war toll, aber warum wurde nur Trompete gespielt?”
- „Du musst das mit dem *Geigenkonzert* im Volkstheater verwechselt haben.”

Wird aus dem Kontext klar, worum es sich handelt, kann man das Substantiv (und damit auch den Artikel) dann auch weglassen: *Markiere das mal mit „TODO”.*

Comment: Die Bundeskanzlerin Angela Merkel wird auch nicht mit Anführungsstrichen geschrieben, oder der Stürmer Müller oder der Dirigent Karajan.

Comment: Das stimmt. In den hier genannten Beispielen ergeben sie meiner Meinung nach Sinn, aber das ist mehr Gefühl als Gewissheit. [Die Regeln dazu](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen) sagen ebenfalls, dass es von den Umständen abhängen kann.

Comment: Diese Regeln sind - erlaube ein klares Wort - Schrott. D.8.1.a "In dem Wort „Tri“athlon steckt das griechische „tri-“ (=drei)." Man muss schon geistig massiv beeinträchtigt sein, um ohne fremde Hilfe das Tri in Triathlon nicht zu finden, nicht. Es ist also eine performative Beleidigung des Lesers, da eine Hervorhebung zu verwenden. 2.a+b "...Nur die Silbermedaille..." - ist keine Ironie, denn Ironie ist versteckter Spott. Hier wird der Spott ja nicht versteckt sondern ausgestellt. Das nennt man Häme. 3.1. geht, weil das Parfum einfach Parfum sein könnte, so am Anfang des Satzes. …

Comment: @userunknown Dass sie "Schrott" sind, ist ohne Evidenz, und diese Aussage kann daher ohne Evidenz verworfen werden.

Comment: … Käme auf den Kontext an. Im 2. Satz geht es nicht, weil es wurde ja gerade gesagt, "aus dem Film" Casablanca, und nicht aus der Stadt. Es kann also nur der Film sein.

Comment: @Adrian: Ist Dir die Evidenz, die ich in meinen Kommentar ausgebreitet habe, entgangen?

Comment: @userunknown du meinst deine mit Beleidigungen gespickte eigene Meinung?

Comment: Bevor das jetzt eskaliert, möchte ich darauf hinweisen, dass es bei dieser Frage hier um den Artikel ging, nicht um Anführungszeichen. Ich habe sie hauptsächlich verwendet, um den von mir betonten Unterschied zwischen *Namen* und *Erläuterunen/Beschreibungen* hervorzuheben. --- Zu den Regeln auf der verlinkten Seite (die ja lediglich als "Hinweise" eingeleitet werden): Über die Beispiele zu streiten ist etwas müßig, da der Kontext fehlt. Es sind eben nur kurze Beispiele für verschiedene Verwendungsmöglichkeiten.

Comment: @user unknown  Abgesehen davon, dass Malte recht hat, dass es hier gar nicht um die Anführungsstriche ging sondern um die Artikel: Beispiela 2.a+b aus der Dudenwebsite zum Gebrauch von Gänsefüßchen ist weder Ironie noch Häme: In *Sie hat "nur" die Silbermedaille gewonnen* zeigen die Gänsefüßchen an, dass sich der Sprecher von der Bedeutung des Wörtchens "nur" distanziert, und zwar in dem Sinne, dass er hervorheben möchte, dass es eine bemerkenswerte Leistung ist, *immerhin* die Silbermedaille zu erringen. Das ist weder Spott noch Häme sondern eigentlich eine Ehrenbekundung.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Richtig, es wird nicht die Sportlerin verspottet, sondern die, denen das zu wenig ist. Wovon distanziert sich der Schreiber hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41003/266 (flexibility, quantifier floating)?

Comment: Es ist ein eingeschliffener Manierismus, der mit der Gießkanne über jedes zweite Fremdwort bzw. allgemein über solche Worte, die den aktiven Wortschatz von 5jährigen überschreiten (rattled, Distanzstellung) so inflationär gestreut wird, dass er zur Hervorhebung gar nicht mehr taugt.

Comment: @MalteHartwig: Kannst Du dann bitte erläutern, wieso, was für Goethes Faust gilt, nicht ebenso für den Film Casablanca gilt? Wenn überhaupt, dann kommt doch hier allenfalls eine umgekehrte Entscheidung in Frage, weil Goethe ja wirklich eine Faust hat, die dem Literaturfremdling geläufiger sein könnte, als sein Stück. Beim Film steht aber das jeden Zweifel ausschließende Film davor.

Comment: @userunknown:  Der Link, den du oben gesetzt hast zu einem - vermute - ich anderen Beispiel für distanzierende Gänsefüßchen funktioniert nicht recht... ich lande im Irgendwo. Prüfst du ihn mal?

Comment: Funktioniert ganz ausgezeichnet bei mir. (Antwort von johnl zu Sentence Structure ...)

Answer (score 9):

Normalerweise würde man

> in der Datei "file.doc"

schreiben. Es ginge aber auch sowas wie

> in der "file.doc"-Datei

Ohne Anführugszeichen wirkt das etwas merkwürdig.

Comment: Auf Stackexchange ginge sogar `file.doc` (mit Gravis-Akzenten).

Comment: Auch wenn sie leider immer unpopulärerer werden, die richtigen Anführungszeichen sind: „ und ”.

Comment: @clemens Stimmt leider auch nicht, die Merkregel ist 99-66, es wären also „Anführungszeichen“.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Oh ja, da bin ich wohl ausversehen gegen die Umstelltaste gedrückt, als ich die Anführungsstriche-Oben getippt habe. Die „99-66-Merkhilfe“ kannte ich noch nicht.

Comment: In der Wellnessregion Oberlausitz, im Kino Odeon, im Veranstaltungssaal Zuse, in der Weltstadt Paris - nirgends besteht Bedarf an Anführungszeichen. Die Behauptung es wirke merkwürdig ist ohne Evidenz und kann daher ohne Evidenz verworfen werden.

Comment: Im Jahre 1812 beschloss der französische Kaiser "Napoleon"...

Answer (score 7):

Wir haben es hier mit der Kollission zweier inkompatibler Systeme zu tun, der Computer-, Betriebs- und Dateisysteme einerseits und andererseits der Grammatik.

Quer dazu liegen Probleme die man ständig mit englischen Fachtermini hat und als weiterer Sonderfall ist der Unterschied von mündlichem und schriftlichem Ausdruck relevant.

> In der file.docx Datei stimmt das Datum nicht.

Nach dt. Grammatik und Rechtschreibung handelt es sich um ein Substantiv, das üblicherweise zusammengeschrieben wird, wie der Holztisch, aber file.docxdatei, welches dann auch groß geschrieben gehörte, und zu File.docxdatei würde, ist einerseits schwer zu erkennen und bei Dateisystemen mit Unterscheidung der Groß-Kleinschreibung auch inhaltlich womöglich falsch.

Die Regeln sind aber nicht da, um den Schreibern das Leben schwer zu machen, sondern um den Lesern die Erfassung zu erleichtern. Um den Eigennamen nicht zu eng mit dem Wesen der Sache zu verbinden würde ich hier zu einem Bindestrich greifen, es bei der Kleinschreibung belassen, so relevant, und eventuell mögliche Auszeichnungen wie Kursivschreibung nutzen, um den Eigennamencharakter des Begriffs hervorzuheben:

> In der *file.docx*-Datei stimmt das Datum nicht.

Gegen den Einsatz von Anführungsstrichen spricht, dass es weder Zitat, noch wörtliche Rede ist, und Anführungsstriche legitme Dateinamensbestandteile sein können.

2. Beispiel:

   > in file.docx Datei ...

Ohne den möglichen Satz kann man hierzu wenig sagen.

> In file.docx Datei stimmt die Rechnungssumme nicht.

Deppenleerzeichen grüßen vom Dach Boden. Das Wort *Datei* ist hier einfach überflüssig - was könnte es sonst sein?

> In file.docx stimmt die Rechnungssumme nicht.

3. Umstellung der Wortfolge:

   > In der Datei file.docx plaudern Sie Geschäftsgeheimnisse aus.

Auch das ist eine elegante Lösung.

4. Weitere Beispiele:

   > Mit (dem?) TEST.01 Label.

Was ist damit?

```
Kaufen Sie das Laufwerk mit dem TEST.01-Label! 
Womit? 
Mit dem TEST.01-Label! Heiner, reich mal ein Laufwerk rüber!
Mit TEST.01-Label? 
Wenn die 02-er noch nicht da sind…
```

In mündlicher Rede sieht man natürlich keine Groß-/Kleinschreibung. In einem Roman würde man eher Test.01-Label schreiben, solange die Schreibweise nicht signifikant ist. So würde ein:

> Peter hatte noch keinen Passwd-Eintrag.

einen Unixadmin wahrscheinlich stören.

Das Todotag würde ich in Prosa eher so schreiben, wie hier, aber in einer E-Mail unter Programmiererkollegen womöglich auch TODO-Tag oder gar @TODO-Tag.

Ob mit oder ohne *dem*, dafür gelten aber die gleichen Regeln wie für Hammer und Messer. Der Mörder tat es mit dem Messer. Der Handwerker kam mit Hammer und Zange.

Comment: Das war eine sehr profunde und schön zu lesende Antwort. Ich möchte jedoch einwenden: Auch der Mörder kann es mit Hammer und Zange getan haben.

Answer (score 3):

Es geht um die drei Bestandteile des Hauptworts, seines Namens und dem Artikel. Gebräuchlich, möglich und bei meinem ehemaligen Arbeitgeber, einem IT-Fachverlag regelmäßig verwendet wurden folgende drei Varianten:

1. Die Datei "/etc/passwd" enthält bei Unix-Systemen die Passwörter.
2. Die "/etc/passwd"-Datei ist wichtig für das Anmelden der Benutzer.
3. Der Angreifer hatte "/etc/passwd" verändert und sich so Zugang verschafft.

Die erste Fassung ist die generischste, entspricht aber oft nicht dem gesprochenen Wort.

Die zweite Fassung erfordert eine Kopplung, die zusammen mit den Anführungszeichen oft ungelenk aussieht, aber an sich korrekt ist.

Die dritte Fassung ist typischer Sprachgebrauch vieler Fachleute in diesem Kontext, allein weil der Typ, der im Hauptwort steckt, meist aus dem Namen hervorgeht. Wenn diese Bedingung gegeben ist, halte ich sie aber für verwendbar.

Comment: Punkt 2 ist überhaupt nicht korrekt. Der Bindestrich verbindet die Wörter, die Anführungsstriche trennen sie wieder. Anführungsstriche mitten im Wort geht nicht. Da alles weder Zitat, noch wörtliche Rede ist, gehören die Anführungsstriche in allen 3 Beispielen gestrichen, am dringlichsten im 2.

Comment: @userunknown Anführungszeichen können (und dürfen) mehr als nur Zitate und wörtliche Reden markieren (z.B. §94 der Regeln des Rechtschreibrats).

Answer (score 2):

Ich studiere Informatik und im Gespräch mit einem Dozenten sage ich:

- "...in der Datei filename.cpp".

Den Punkt im Namen spreche ich als 'dot' oder Punkt aus.
Allerdings, wenn ich mit Kommilitonen spreche, sage ich:

- "Öffne mal die filename txt."

Ohne einen Punkt, aber *mit* Artikel. Es gibt allerdings auch Leute, die es ohne Artikel sagen. Der Artikel klingt vom Sprachgefühl her richtig.

Comment: Ich habe Informatik studiert, und ich sage immer "Öffne mal *filename.txt*". Ein Artikel dort klingt für mich seltsam. :-)

Comment: Ok, wir haben da 2 Informatik-Studierende, mit den unterschiedlichen Meinungen. Das ist schon mal Interessant.

Comment: Noch ein Infer hier, der mit Artikel spricht.

Comment: Hier ein Informatiker, der den Artikel nur verwendet, wenn auch "Datei" dabei steht. Also entweder *öffne mal die Datei README.TXT* oder *öffne mal README.TXT*.

Comment: Wenn Du gesprochene Rede wiedergibst, wieso schreibst Du dann das Substantiv nicht groß?