# Unfälle hat es an dieser Stelle schon einige gegeben

Tags: sentence-structure

What does the indefinite pronoun *einige* point to, in this sentence?

Comment: *beträchtliche Anzahl, ziemlich viele; nicht wenige*  
I am not sure what your question is, since it lacks correctness in English grammar..

Comment: Es gibt an dieser Stelle schon einige Unfälle.

Comment: @RoyPJ *wenige, nicht allzuviele, etwas* - "Einige" can both mean "few" and "quite a few"

Comment: @tofro Indeed, but in this context it describes that more than a few have happened.
To owner: can you please state your question? Do you want the meaning of *einige*? What do you mean with *point*?

Comment: @RoyPJ In what context? I seem to fail to see any.

Comment: @tofro In this sentence I meant. But since the question now got changed, a translation is not needed anymore anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a much better question than the downvotes are suggesting :).

Grammatically, what you can observe here is the so-called "Distanzstellung" of an *indefinitum* (here: "einige"). With that in mind, just note that the sentence is basically a "rattled" version of

> An dieser Stelle hat es schon einige Unfälle gegeben.

The reason is generally contextual, but preferences also vary regionally. (You provide no context.)

Such a "flexibility" can be observed with other *indefinita* as well, e.g. *kein* or *manche*. It's not confined to German, but a phenomenon observed across a wide variety of languages (the term of art is "quantifier floating", should you wish to dig deeper).

Comment: I'm afraid this answer misses to answer the question, as far as I understand it.

Comment: Can you please explain, why you put so many words in quotation marks? Distanzstellung, rattled, flexibility and quantifier floating, what do you really mean, if not, what the words usually mean?

Comment: @userunknown I see nothing unusual about putting words from another language in quotation marks. "Rattled" and "flexibility" are non-technical, transferred terms. And in "the term X", it is entirely normal to put X either in quotation marks or italics. Not sure why you would think that quotations marks necessarily indicate a deviation from the ordinary meaning.

Comment: There is no help in putting unusual words in quotation marks. Quotation marks are mainly used for direct speech and citation. You don't cite anyone, nor is there a different speaker. It indicates a change in the speaker, a different voice. Why would I change my voice at these words? There is no reason to do so. Another usage is, if there is an ambiguity and you want to to underline the usage of a word, not for the normal thing it stands for, but for the word as word. But in cases like "The term of art is ..." it is clear, that now the term follows, no need for emphasize.

Comment: And what's wrong with "Distanzstellung"? Why is it only so-called? What is it in real? How should it be called? In English sentences, I can't see a problem with "rattled" which is ordinary English, isn't it? Some people talked about the "so called >> DDR <<" to underline, that it is only called democratic, while it in fact was not. What else is the purpose of so-called in your expression? If you put an ordinary word like flexibility in quotes, I wonder what you mean instead. Obviously not what flexibility normally means. http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/anfuhrungszeichen.php

Comment: @userunknown Thanks for the harangue. I am very sorry if my response does not meet your quality expectations. The massive abuse of quotation marks in our society may go down as one of the greatest obstacles to intellectual progress, and I'm glad you pointed it out in so many words. You'll be happy to learn, however, that, prompted by your comments, I have found out it's not necessary to click an extra button to italicize text on this site, so you may see less quotation marks from me in the future.

Comment: I think the English term for this is _floating quantifier_. See for instance here: http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Floating_quantifier

Answer (score 0):

It means "a few" and is talking about a few accidents. Unfälle are accidents.